# C# how to delete item from datagridview (current item cannot be removed from the list because there is no current item)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Reject button in datagridview like this:

[image]

When i select anr row and click on that button, that row must remove from datagridview,but something went wrong,it gives me error:

> Current item cannot be removed from the list because there is no current item.

What's the problem?

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    if (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Reject")
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to reject this bid?",
            "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == 
            DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            creditRequestsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: The code which you shared is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  it's very big code,What do u want i share more?

Comment: *it's very big code* ← that's why you should create a [MCVE]. At the first step it will help you to find and solve the problem yourself in a clean environment. Then if you couldn't find the problem yourself, it will help other users to reproduce exactly the same the problem which you are facing with, then they can solve the problem for you.

Comment: There could be multiple scenarios leading to the error which you shared. Without knowing what and how you are trying to do, the Q/A will turn into a guess game which will result in wasting a lot of time.

Comment: How is your binding source set up?
I have no problem at all making this work with a simple `List<>` and a `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct. The 'current' item in the list is not set. Try using either the `Remove()` or `RemoveAt()` functions, passing either the item from the binding source or the index of the item, respectively.